# CentOS 5.5 remote kickstart installation stalls at "Starting install process." How to debug?

Tags: centos, installation, rhel5, kickstart

I'm having a difficult time with a remote CentOS 5.5 kickstart installation on an HP ProLiant DL360 G6. This is in an environment where I maintain an internal CentOS yum repository. The kickstart installation and post scripts have been tested and normally work. This hardware is also common in this environment, so I do not believe that it is a factor. Unfortunately, I'm having problems with a specific server install.

The system is remote to the yum repository at a distance of 500 miles. They are connected over a private 100-megabit layer 2 connection (26ms round-trip). I'm mounting the 10mb CentOS 5 netinstall ISO image via an HP ILO remote console. The initial boot parameters are:

`linux ks=http://yum.abctrading.com/prop.cfg ksdevice=eth0 ip=x.x.x.x dns=x.x.x.x netmask=255.255.255.0 gateway=x.x.x.x`

I'm using the `url --url http://ks.abctrading.com/5.5/os/x86_64/` method of installation. This quickly boots into the anaconda installer, pulls the kickstart config and formats the drives. The process eventually halts at the screen below, reading `"Starting install process."`. Going to the other virtual consoles give the second image below. The process stalls at this point and cannot proceed with the rest of the installation. Running the same kickstart config locally works just fine. I've tried mounting the boot ISO from the console as well as from the ILO2 command line pointing to a locally-hosted boot ISO via http.

How can I debug this? Are there any options I've overlooked?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is `dns=` valid? I thought it was `nameserver=`?  You seem to indicate it's getting past that part, so I guess so.

Comment: From the boot screen it's `dns=`. In the actual kickstart file, it's `nameserver=`.

Comment: I don't see any thing helpful in that second screenshot. Try changing the log level to debug and see if you get any thing more useful? I believe that's `loglevel=debug` on the boot line.  Or in the Kickstart script with the `logging --level=debug` statement.

Comment: I've done remote CentOS installs and have has the anaconda stall out at this point for a half-hour, and then suddenly resume. How long have you waited?

Comment: Watch the logs on the http server? (access_log, error_log) Maybe it's just caching RPMs on the remote server before starting the install.

Comment: I gave it 70 minutes the last time.

Comment: Watching the web logs, I see RPM requests being served slowly, every few seconds... It's as though it's attempting to cache all of the RPMs before starting the package installation.

Comment: So, it's working? It's just going to take even longer than 70 minutes?  I'll submit that as an answer rather than a comment if you don't mind accepting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running this installation via NFS solved the performance issue. Unfortunately, the `urlgrabber` portion of Yum in the post-install scripts was slow like the initial http installation attempts. The narrows the focus to the implementation of Yum's urlgrabber and something with the line distance and low-latency connection. Once the system was booted into the newly-installed OS, yum speeds were fine.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's caching RPMs on the remote server.  Watch (`tail -f /var/log/httpd/access_log`) the access_log on the http server to check for activity.

Comment: They key here is to debug the slow yum downloads. It seems to be a tcp scaling issue. I'm going to keep working with network parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this problem caused by a DNS issue.

Determine the hostname of the URL being used by anaconda, and add it to `/etc/hosts`:

```
# echo 192.168.1.1 my.server.example.com >> /etc/hosts
```

anaconda immediately speeds up.