# centos installlation through netinstall

Tags: centos

I am trying to install centos 5.5 x86_64 through netinstall .I downloaded the iso and burned to a CD/DVD. Then I tried installing through HTTP.

Web site name: mirror.centos.org

CentOS directory for x86_64: /centos/5.5/os/x86_64

Everything went fine until Installation .it said Installation may take several minutes. Please wait . 
Then it started throwing error saying device-mapper1.02.rpm cannot be opened etc.And when i retry, the window saying the message "Starting install process this may take several minutes" is stuck for long duration .

Am i doing something wrong ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: [CentOS 5.5 remote kickstart installation stalls at "Starting install process." How to debug?](https://serverfault.com/questions/242957/centos-5-5-remote-kickstart-installation-stalls-at-starting-install-process-ho)

Maybe try another CentOS mirror for the installation. [Search for one close to your location](http://www.centos.org/modules/tinycontent/index.php?id=30). It could be a firewall issue as well.

Comment: The other mirror helped :)